# 'Main' method suitable for an entry point error in SharePoint Event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012

I have created a simple list  event receiver with item adding,updating,and deleting events in SharePoint 2013. But some how it is giving me a strange build error when i try to deploy the event receiver. Following is the error which i get

> Add User to Department Contacts.exe' does not contain a static 'Main'
>   method suitable for an entry point

Here  Add User to Department Contacts is the name of my project.

Has anybody encountered this error? If yes how to overcome it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have compile set on the file properties.

e.g.

single click "Feature1.EventReciver.cs" within solution explorer. Now look at the properties tab and you should see build action.... make sure its set to compile.

same goes for anything else within the project

Comment: your solutions solved that problem but now it is giving another build error "Error:A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods  1
"

Comment: This is strange it is just a simple event receiver

Comment: I deleted the event receiver and created a new one and now its working. But i still don't know what was the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: that is simple, you were adding in code directly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175781/a-namespace-cannot-directly-contain-members-such-as-fields-or-methods-in-net-r

Comment: the entire class and namespace code was generated automatically when i selected event receiver template in visual studio. and i had not written a single word by my self and just deployed it. But i got that message.

Comment: ok that is strange! could be related to the initial build the first time round that screwed up the code? glad to see tho it worked just by recreating it.